# r knitr - embedded HTML tags being escaped - how to turn off

Tags: html, r, knitr

I am having a little trouble with knitr and embedded html tables.  Basically what is happening is when I embed xtable output in html, the html tags are being escaped rending the output unreadable. the output of print.xtable does seems to correctly produce the expected output (an html table) but then when knit is called on the document that xtable is embedded into, escaped characters are produced.  Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Version and code example below:

- RStudio 0.98.1103
- R 3.13
- knitr 1.9

  ```
  library("knitr")
  library("xtable")

  col1 <- c(1, 2, 3) 
  col2 <- c("a", "b", "c") 
  col3 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
  df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)

  # display the dataframe 
  df

  # HTML is properly generated here
  tbl <- print(xtable(df),type="HTML",include.rownames=FALSE)

  testknitr <- "<html>
  <head>
  <title>Test Knitr from variable</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Testing Knitr escaping </h1>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <!--begin.rcode label=\"a table\" 
  tbl 
  end.rcode-->
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>"

  # inspecting the file will show all < replaced with &lt; and > replaced with &gt;
  # and new lines replaced with \n, which does not render properly in a browser
  knit(text=testknitr, output="testknitr.html")}
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `results="asis"` option.

Try the following:

```
testknitr <- "<html>
              <head>
                  <title>Test Knitr from variable</title>
              </head>
              <body>
                  <h1>Testing Knitr escaping </h1>
                  <table>
                      <tr>
                         <td>
               <!--begin.rcode label=\"a table\", results=\"asis\", echo=FALSE
                    print(xtable(df),
                          type=\"HTML\", 
                          include.rownames=FALSE) 
               end.rcode-->
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>"

knit(text=testknitr, output="testknitr.html")
```

Also, print the output of xtable in the code chunk to avoid unnecessary newline characters.

Comment: Thank you szabad!  That almost got it all.  still a few errant \n's around but much closer!

Comment: actually I had one more typo, so your solution fixed it!  thank you so much!